# Swift readLine! is causing fatal error "execution was interrupted"

Tags: swift, readline

I have this piece of code

```
func sell() throws{
    while(true)
    {
        var choice : String?
        print("Please press a number from 1 to 3\n")
        let product = readLine(stripNewline: true)!
        switch product
        {
            case "1":
                //
            case "2":
                //
            case "3":
                //
            default:
                choice = "Invalid"
                try sell()
        }
}

try sell()
```

And it gives me the error

> execution was interrupted reason exc_bad_instruction

I realized that the ! is causing the error. If I remove it I have a problem with the comparisons inside `switch`.

Anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
func foo()->Int {
    print("Please press a number from 1 to 3")
    while true {
        if let l = readLine(),
            let i = Int(l) {
            if (1..<4).contains(i) {
                return i
            } else {
                print("Number must be in range from 1 to 3")
            }
        } else {
            print("Please press a number")
        }
    }
}
let r = foo()
print("You chose", r)
```

an example of ...

```
Please press a number from 1 to 3
u
Please press a number
7
Number must be in range from 1 to 3
45
Number must be in range from 1 to 3
h76
Please press a number
1
You chose 1
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

How about create one if let to check if this contains value or is it nil

```
    let product = readLine(stripNewline: true)
    if let productNo = product {
        switch productNo {
          //your same code in switch
}
```